LITE_SERVER_UNKNOWN: cannot apply external message to current state : Failed to unpack account state. When creating ton wallet
I`ve faced issue when trying to create ton wallet according to documentation. I am always having this error: LITE_SERVER_UNKNOWN: cannot apply external message to current state : Failed to unpack account state
Here is my code
    const tonwebInstance = new TonWeb(
      new TonWeb.HttpProvider("https://toncenter.com/api/v2/jsonRPC", {
        apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
      })
    );

    // Create a key pair
    const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair();

    // Extract the public key from the key pair
    const publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
    const publicKeyHex = Buffer.from(publicKey).toString("hex");

    // Extract the private key from the key pair
    const privateKey = keyPair.secretKey;
    const privateKeyHex = Buffer.from(privateKey).toString("hex");

    console.log("key pair created");

    // Create a wallet using the public key as Uint8Array
    const wallet = tonwebInstance.wallet.create({ publicKey });

    console.log("wallet created");

    // Get the wallet address
    const walletAddress = (await wallet.getAddress()).toString(
      true,
      true,
      true
    );

    console.log("wallet address: " + walletAddress);

    const seqno = await wallet.methods.seqno().call();

    await wallet.deploy(privateKey).send();

From the internet i havent found any working solution, except that it is somehow depends on seqno, but i dont really now how. from debugging i can see that error appearns on send() method. What should i do?
